# Passwords when setup signing of android app in AppCenter

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-app-center

When setting up building of Android app in App-center, I must upload a keystore file for signing the app. 
I must then give it:
- Keystore password
- Key alias
- Key password

But I only have an alias and password.

It is some time ago I created the keystore, but looking into this guide, they only mention an alias and *one* password.
https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows
... But I must give it *two* passwords.

Please help :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `keytool` command line utility you can specify two passwords, but one is optional in which case the same password is used in both cases. Did you try entering the same password in both places?

Comment: True. After a while I tried entering same password for both. It worked!